# Does useEffect determine whether component rerendring?

Tags: reactjs

now I'm on migrating class based component into functional components. Based on my knowledge, lifecycle methods `componentDidUpdate` , `componentWillUnmount`,`componentDidMount` can be replaced with `useEffect` hooks.

Does `useEffect` hooks has nothing to do with `shouldComponentUpdate` and can't determine whether component re-renders or not?

Comment: Check the accepted answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54551949/react-hooks-how-do-i-implement-shouldcomponentupdate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`useEffect` runs based on changes on its dependency array. It can be used as `componentDidMount`:

```
// empty [] dependency array -> use effect runs once after mount
useEffect(() => {}, [])
```

For `shouldComponentUpdate` , look here: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-do-i-implement-shouldcomponentupdate

You can use React.memo for that:

```
const Button = React.memo((props) => {
  // your component
});
```

Answer (score 0):

in general, useEffect runs when a state object updates, it's seperate from re-rendering. the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) are pretty good btw.