# React: Best way to set state in parent with value from child

Tags: reactjs, state, parent

First question here i go... I´ve been searching and couldn´t find the *best practice*.

My solution (Maybe stupid):
I have a **parent** form that has a child select.

```
const [periodo, setPeriodo] = useState('0')

const  cambiarPeriodo=(e)=> { setPeriodo(e) }

<NewSelect value ={periodo} onchange={(e) => { cambiarPeriodo(e) }}  />
```

The child function component select:

```
const  periodosChange=(e)=> {
  props.onchange(e.target.value);

}
<Select value={props.value} custom name="periodo" id="periodo"  onChange={periodosChange}  >
```

Options are populated via axios database query with a **useEffect**.

When user selects an option in list, fires a **onchange** callback function and set state in parent.

Because of setState, the parent and child reloaded and cleared the user selection. The solution was to pass via prop the state to the child and assign it in value of select. *<Select **value={props.value}**..*

**Is there any better way to do it**, or this is a standard procedure? Actually i would like the child not to reload at all because the select list wont ever change... Tried React.memo but couldn´t make it work

Comment: That’s standard procedure.

Answer (score 0):

There is a class-based component lifecycle's hook called [`shouldComponentUpdate()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html) which you can use to prevent the child component from re-rendering if the list won't change. But this means you will have to convert your child component from a functional component to a class-based component.

The other option would be to use [`useMemo()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo) and memoize the entire component as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57405307/1931451).

Comment: Great thanks!! I´ll give it a try, make the static select a class makes sense.