# React lifecycle methods to hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have simple blog with articles. And I want to rewrite classes to functional components and hooks.
Now I got this logic in lifecycle methods for my page with edit/add form:
it works fine.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
 if (this.props.match.params.id !== prevProps.match.params.id) {
    if (prevProps.match.params.id) {
        this.props.onUnload();
      }

      this.id = this.props.match.params.id;
        if (this.id) {
            return this.props.onLoad(userService.articles.get(this.id));
        }
        this.props.onLoad(null);
   }
   this.isLoading = false;
}

componentDidMount() {
  if (this.id) {
    this.isLoading = true;
    return this.props.onLoad(userService.articles.get(this.id));
  }
  this.isLoading = false;
  this.props.onLoad(null);
}
   
componentWillUnmount() {
   this.props.onUnload();
}
   
shouldComponentUpdate(newProps, newState) {
   if (this.props.match.params.id !== newProps.match.params.id) {
      this.isLoading = true;
   }
   return true;
}
```

I rewrote it all to hooks like that:

```
//componentDidMount
  useEffect(() => {
    if (id) {
      setIsloading(true);
      return props.onLoad(userService.articles.get(id));
    }
    setIsloading(false);
    props.onLoad(null);
  }, []);

  useEffect(()=> {
      prevId.current = id;
      }, [id]
  );

  //componentDidUpdate
  useEffect(() => {
    //const id = props.match.params.id;
    if (id !== prevId.current) {
      if (prevId.current) {
        props.onUnload();
      }
      if (id) {
        return props.onLoad(userService.articles.get(id));
      }
      props.onLoad(null);
    }
    setIsloading(false);
  });

  //componentWillUnmount
  useEffect(() => {
     return props.onUnload();
  }, []);
```

1. I got error - "Too many re-renders." at codesandbox
   full code:  [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/immutable-silence-9prc4?file=/src/components/Articles/ArticleEditor.js)

Its strange, but at localhost there is no error "Too many re-renders."

2. Don't know what to do with my class "shouldComponentUpdate" method how to rewrite it to hooks. Tryed 'memo' but have no idea how to write in in this case.
3. And anyway I'm missing something, because it all won't work - it's not updating form fields properly.

If you have a good knowledge with react hooks please help, or give some advice - how to fix it?

Comment: Read a bit more how `useEffect` hook works. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects

Comment: ty. I did it and in my code i have dependencies for useEffect when it need it. Did i miss something?

Comment: yeah, I see a couple of `useEffect`s without any dependencies.

Comment: This might help you a bit? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54551949/react-hooks-how-do-i-implement-shouldcomponentupdate

Comment: I see only "componentDidUpdate( )" without deps, cos it should run everytime. Do I wrong and it should have deps too?

Comment: @cpppatrick, ty. I have very weak knowledge in hooks. It is first time i tryed to use it. tryed use "memo" like in tutorial, but have no result yet. errors errors errors :(

Answer (score 3):

The effect without dependency is causing `"Too many re-renders."`: it runs after every render then it calls `setIsLoading` to update the state( `loading`) which will cause the component to re-render, which will run the `effect` again and the `setState` will be called again and `effect` and so on...

```
//componentDidUpdate
  useEffect(() => {
    //const id = props.match.params.id;
    if (id !== prevId.current) {
      if (prevId.current) {
        props.onUnload();
      }
      if (id) {
        return props.onLoad(userService.articles.get(id));
      }
      props.onLoad(null);
    }
    setIsloading(false);
  })
```

to fix the issue either remove the `setIsLoading` from it, or add `IsLoading` as dependency.

```
//componentDidUpdate
  useEffect(() => {
    ...
    setIsloading(false);
  },[isLoading]);
```

---

you can also merge two mount effects into one like this ( yours is also working, but I think this is stylistically preferable):

```
//componentDidMount
  useEffect(() => {
    if (id) {
      setIsloading(true);
      return props.onLoad(userService.articles.get(id));
    }
    setIsloading(false);
    props.onLoad(null);

    //componentWillUnmount
    return function () {
      props.onUnload()
    }
  }, []);
```

for the second bullet: about rewriting your component's `shouldComponentUpdate`; first I must point that your existing `shouldComponentUpdate` isn't sound reasonable, since you always return `true`, and you are only using it to trigger `loading` state; and its not eligible to be written with [React.memo](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) (which is ~equivalent of `shouldComponentUpdate` in class components); so you only need something to be executed on every props change to determine `loading` state and for that you can use an effect with `props` as its dependency like this:

```
//manually keeping old props id
const prevPropsId = useRef();

useEffect(() => {
   if (prevPropsId.current !== props.match.params.id) {
      setIsLoading(true);
   }
   prevPropsId.current = props.match.params.id;
 }, [props.match.params.id]);
// this hook only run if `props.match.params.id` change
```

based on my realization this shall do the job, ( despite having hard time understanding why you write the logic this way in the first place) and if it's not doing fine you may tune the logic a little bit to match your needs, you get the idea how the props change effect works. also you many need to handle `typeError` in case `id`, `params` or `match` doesn't exist and
[Optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) can be handy tool here -> `props.match?.params?.id`

Comment: thank you. I did changes. Now I heven't errors. But I have lot warnings about useEffect's deps. And it still not do what my old class code lifecycles methods did :(

Comment: I think thats might be becouse of I still can't write hook for my old "shouldComponentUpdate" tryed different things with "memo" but nothing work.

Comment: @WillBlack check out the update on rewriting your `shouldComponentUpdate`

Comment: thanks again. I did all changes you send, but it still not work properly. I think I just missing something simple in my code, and just can't figure it out :(. No errors, no warnings. Can you please see code at codesandbox? 
 https://codesandbox.io/s/immutable-silence-9prc4?file=/src/components/Articles/ArticleEditor.js

Answer (score 2):

If you miss the old lifecycle hooks, you could always recreate them as custom hooks:

```
function useComponentDidMount(effect) {
  useEffect(() => {
    effect();
  }, []);
}
function useComponentWillUnmount(effect) {
  useEffect(() => {
    return effect;
  }, []);
}
function useComponentDidUpdate(effect, dependencies) {
  const hasMountedRef = useRef(false);
  const prevDependenciesRef = useRef(null)
  useEffect(() => {
    // don't run on first render, only on subsequent changes
    if (!hasMountedRef.current) {
      hasMountedRef.current = true;
      prevDependenciesRef.current = dependencies;
      return;
    }
    // run effect with previous dependencies, like in componentDidUpdate!
    effect(...prevDependenciesRef.current || []);
    prevDependenciesRef.current = dependencies;
  }, dependencies)
}
```

Usage (your example refactored):

```
  //componentDidMount
  useComponentDidMount(() => {
    if (id) {
      setIsloading(true);
      props.onLoad(userService.articles.get(id));
      return;
    }
    setIsloading(false);
    props.onLoad(null);
  });

  //componentDidUpdate
  useComponentDidUpdate((prevId) => {
    if (prevId) {
      props.onUnload();
    }
    if (id) {
      props.onLoad(userService.articles.get(id));
      return;
    }
    props.onLoad(null);
    setIsloading(false);
  }, [id]);

  //componentWillUnmount
  useComponentWillUnmount(() => {
     props.onUnload();
  });
```